# Please help me pass data from a service to an activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am attempting to make a simple introductory app that allows the user to provide two numbers to the app via text fields, add the two numbers via service, and then pass the value back to my main activity, where it will be displayed via a textview. The problem is that I get an error when trying to pass the answer back to my main activity. I know a service should not be used for this simple operation, but as I said earlier, this is introductory.

Here is my main activity code:

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

MyService myService;
boolean isBound = false;
private static TextView entry;
private static EditText entry1;
private static EditText entry2;

public void addAllTheNumbers(View view){
    entry1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry1);
    entry2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry2);
    entry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    final String s = entry1.getText().toString();
    final String s1 = entry2.getText().toString();

    Intent n = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    n.putExtra("firstNumber", s);
    n.putExtra("secondNumber", s1);
    startService(n);

    Bundle answerData = getIntent().getExtras();
    String e = answerData.getString("e");

    entry.setText(e);
}
```

Here is the service code:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {

private final IBinder ryansBinder = new MyLocaleBinder();

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return ryansBinder;

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    String comeOn = intent.getStringExtra("firstNumber");
    String man = intent.getStringExtra("secondNumber");


    int firstNum = 0;
    int secondNum = 0;

    try {
        firstNum = Integer.parseInt(comeOn);
        secondNum = Integer.parseInt(man);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return Integer.parseInt(null);
    }

    int sum;

    sum = firstNum + secondNum;

    String answer1 = String.valueOf(sum);

    Intent t = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    t.putExtra("s",answer1);

    return START_STICKY;
}





public class MyLocaleBinder extends Binder{
    MyService getService(){
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
}
```

And finally, my error code:

```
08-12 17:37:50.252  31546-31546/com.example.vanessaanthony.myfirstservice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vanessaanthony.myfirstservice, PID: 31546
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.example.vanessaanthony.myfirstservice.MainActivity.addAllTheNumbers(MainActivity.java:38)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a service, it runs aside the Activity, not synchronously with it as if it were another method. It looks like you expect that the intent will come back from the service into the onCreate, which it won't as it'll be trying to read the Intent when it just isn't there.

Take a look at using a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) instead. Create a receiver to get the intent from the service, then in that receiver update the UI with the result.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you should not use a service for this, but just whatching your code
    String e = answerData.getString("e");

You are trying yo get "e".

t.putExtra("s",answer1);

You are passing " s" and should be "e".

Dont know if will work.

But another way is to use activities for result.

Regards.